# System.ArgumentException: Column 'COLUMN_NAME' does not belong to table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, chart.js, jsonresult

I am trying to return an SP result usign JSon Method just like in this tutorial, http://prashantjayle.blogspot.com/2015/05/chartjs-with-aspnet-mvc-5.html, but when I run it, the chart I need doesn't display on the view.

In my Controller, I have this code:

```
 public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
        List<string> lstSales = new List<string>();
        List<string> lstProduct = new List<string>();


        string strQuery = "SP_SALES_PER_PRODUCT";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ebms_connection"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dtTable);


        foreach(DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
        {
            lstSales.Add(row["TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM"].ToString());
            lstProduct.Add(row["PRODUCT_CODE"].ToString()); 
        }


        var BarChart = new
        {

            SALES = lstSales,
            PRODUCTS = lstProduct
        };
        return Json (BarChart, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And the error points to this line of code:

```
lstSales.Add(row["TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM"].ToString());
```

TOTAL_AMT_PER ITEM is the column I call in my SP.
This is my SP query

```html
SELECT p.PRODUCT_CODE, SUM(case when p.PRODUCT_ID=od.PRODUCT_ID and od.ORDER_ID=o.ORDER_ID then od.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM else 0 end)
FROM [ORDER] o
INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAILS od
ON o.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCT p
ON od.PRODUCT_ID=p.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY p.PRODUCT_CODE
```

What am i doing wrong? Hope someone can help me on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT_CODE, SUM(case when p.PRODUCT_ID=od.PRODUCT_ID and    od.ORDER_ID=o.ORDER_ID then od.TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM else 0 end) 
as TOTAL_AMT_PER_ITEM
FROM [ORDER] o
INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAILS od
ON o.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCT p
ON od.PRODUCT_ID=p.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY p.PRODUCT_CODE
```

You missed an alias name for the sum of case expression, You can try running your original query and can see if result set has the column name what you are expecting to make sure.